# Обращение к переменным страницы с расширения Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

На странице пользователя Steam есть JavaScript код вида

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    g_rgProfileData = {"url":"http:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/id\/****\/","steamid":"****","personaname":"****","summary":"*****"};
</script>
```

Пишу дополнение к браузеру Google Chrome в котором нужно манипулировать с переменной `g_rgProfileData.steamid`, но не могу понять как ее изъять...

Попробовал включить свой js в тело страницы, достал нужную переменную, создал скрытый input, присвоил ему значение steamid, но при обработке расширение просто не видит созданный элемент (input)

Файл, который включается в тело страницы, выполняет следующий код:

```
var STEAMID = window.g_rgProfileData.steamid;
var ets2mp_div = document.createElement("div");
ets2mp_div.innerHTML = "<input type='hidden' name='steamid_jackrv' value='" + STEAMID + "' />";
placeHolder = document.getElementsByClassName("profile_header");
placeHolder[0].appendChild(ets2mp_div);
```

В основном скрипте при попытке достать переменную

```
STEAMID = document.getElementsByName("steamid_jackrv").value;
```

я получаю `undefinded`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByName`, как следует из названия, возвращает массив. Разумеется, у массива не будет свойства value.

Возьмите нулевой элемент массива - и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Уже было обрадовался что проблема наконец решится. Но, увы, ничего не изменилось массив (а вернее NodeList) getElementsByName - пустой :(

Comment: На самом деле я не в то время запрашивал результат.. Правка времени исполнения - решила исход!

Answer (score 5):

Вообще, напрямую доступа к переменным нет, хотя и есть доступ к DOM.
Как правило, решают эту проблему следующим образом:

- Создаётся скрипт, который инжектируется в тело страницы;
- Скрипт считывает необходимые данные и записывает их в DOM;
- Расширение обращается к DOM'у и получает необходимые данные.

Выглядит это следующим образом:

в файле `manifest.json`:

```
"web_accessible_resources" : ["/js/contentScript.js"],
```

в файле `contentScript.js`:

```
function injectScript(file, node) {
    var th = document.getElementsByTagName(node)[0];
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    s.setAttribute('src', file);
    th.appendChild(s);
}
injectScript( chrome.extension.getURL('/js/my_file.js'), 'body');
```

ну и в файле `my_file.js`:

```
// Read your variable from here and do stuff with it
console.log(window.my_variable);
```

Подробно данная методика описана здесь:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499994/ (англ.)

Comment: Я так же и делаю (добавил свой код в вопросе), но вы не показали как оперировать этой переменной а не просто вывести ее в лог браузера..

Comment: @jackrv: в hidden вполне можно записывать. Её главное передать в DOM, hidden для этого вполне подходит

Comment: так я ж так и делаю, проблема в том что я не могу значение hidden получить...

Comment: @jackrv: я знаю, что вы так делаете, вы же в вопросе написали об этом, я просто говорю, что это совершенно нормально, и доступ к DOM у вас есть как из расширения, так и со страницы. То есть, это правильный способ. У вас где-то мелкая неточность, скорее всего, а подход в целом правильный

Comment: Решил проблему через куки, считаю что это не правильно, но работает...

Answer (score 0):

На текущий момент реализовал через cookies
Принцип такой как описал @Igor Chubin, но передача переменной в inject-файле реализована так:

```
document.cookie = "steamid_jackrv=" + window.g_rgProfileData.steamid;
```

В основном скрипте осталось только извлечь мою куку

```
var steamid = getCookie('steamid_jackrv');    
function getCookie(name) {
      var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
        "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
      ));
      return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
    }
```

Все работает, хотя периодически кука не успевает обновится, приходится проверять обновлением. Жду еще мнений а пока ответ @Igor Chubin является главным претендентом на "Правильный ответ"!..

Answer (score 0):

В content script

```
function get_dom_var(var_name) {
    $('head').append('<script id="script_steamhelper">$J("head").append("<input type=\'hidden\' id=\'varSteamHelper\' value=\'" + JSON.stringify(' + var_name + ') + "\'>");</script>');
    data = JSON.parse($('#varSteamHelper').val()); //getVar
    // clear dom data
    $('#varSteamHelper').remove();
    $('#script_steamhelper').remove();
    return data;
}
```